# How does Rails know where the MySQL database is?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I finally got a MySQL database hooked up to a Rails 3.2 app after spending half the day figuring it out.

What I don't understand though is how Rails knows where to find the database?

With the default Sqlite3 it's easy enough in that it's embedded in the app so it's just a matter of specifying the path in the *`database.yml`* (`db/devlopment.sqlite3`).

But, when it's MySQL, I thought I'd have to specify the path of the database I'd created from the MySQL command line.  Turns out I don't have to, all I have to do is give the name of the database and user login credentials.

So when I run a migration in Rails, how does it know where the database is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a reasonable default. Take a look in your `database.yml` file, you might find a line like this:

```
socket = socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

AFAIK, if that's not explicitly there, it is used as the default in the absence of other parameters (such as `host` and `port`).

Comment: Thilo is right --- check the source at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html and you'll see the defaults for host, port, and socket are sane defaults.

Comment: Ok, I don't have the socket parameter set in my `database.yml` file, but I do have the host set to 127.0.0.1 & I don't even need to have that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Rails doesn't know anything about it. The modules which handle the connection to the database are the adapters used by Active Record. Rails only provides a kind of "configuration convention" in the case of the database.yml file to make it somehow "common" to all database possibilities, but internally they use this information to setup each database connection in its own unique protocol. I don't know about SQlite, but the mysql and mysql2 handlers are not mantained by the rails team

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Here you can check out the interface Rails/ActiveRecord uses to setup the MySql Connection.

So, to sum it up, Rails doesn't know. It just needs the information you setup in the database.yml to infer which adapter they should use (go to your database.yml and you'll see something like "adapter: mysql2" or "adapter: "sqlite") and the necessary information to establish the connection. As @pjam described, the protocol used for accessing the mysql service externally is expressed by the pattern mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME?user=YOUR_USER_NAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD , and this is actually how the adapter sets the connection up. Just it is not done by Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it finds it with the url of your local database, which is something like

```
mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME?user=YOUR_USER_NAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

So it only needs DB_NAME, YOUR_USER_NAME & YOUR_PASSWORD, which are provided in your `database.yml`